# Shell: How to get FD of an open port

Tags: shell, sockets, port, file-descriptor

Background: A java process binds to a port. The java process now starts a shell script in a subprocess (using jdk8s -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError). This shell script successfully shutdown the java process. Unfortunately it cannot restart the java process, as the port is still bound to the subprocess...

I know, that i can close any FD, even those connected to sockets. So my current solution is

```
INODE=$(netstat -tulpen  | grep ":$PORT " | awk '{print $8}')
FD_SOCKET=$(ls -l /proc/$$/fd | grep socket | grep "\[$INODE\]" | grep -o " [0-9]\+ -> " | awk '{print $1}')
eval "exec $FD_SOCKET>&-"
```

This actually works, but how to avoid this pipe monster?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forcing the socket closed, how about allowing the OS to take care of it by letting all processes that have inherited it terminate?  That includes the script itself, of course, and any process that it might launch directly, but it should work to use the `at` command to schedule the relaunch.

Thus, after the old VM has finished shutting down, the script could ignore the socket issue and simply do this:

```
at -M now + 0 minutes >/dev/null <<EOF
java com.my.Server.class &
EOF
```

I presume you are already aware that you might need to use `Socket.setReuseAddress()` when the new process creates the socket.